# 301 redirect php file to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

**I would like to 301 redirect the following url:**

http://www.olddomain.com/colectii.php?colec_sel=162 ->
http://www.newdomain.com/25-baterii-chiuveta-de-bucatarie

**This is as close as I got:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^colectii.php?colec_sel=162$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect-url [R=301,L]
```

**It does work if I try to redirect like this:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^categ=baterii-de-chiuveta$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect-url [R=301,L]
```

...but if i include"colectii.php?", it does not.

I only have 2 URLs to redirect, but I can't get it to work, I have tried pretty much everything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since, you've tried pretty much everything, how do we know what didn't work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%{QUERY_STRING} variable doesnt contain file name, try :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^colec_sel=162$
RewriteRule ^colectii\.php$ redirect-url? [R=301,L]
```

an empty question mark at the end of the target url is important as it discards the old query strings.